# How dismiss AppStoreOverlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, overlay

I'm trying to create an overlay to display an app banner and wish I could dismiss it with some conditions. I found the dismiss method in the Xcode documentation, but I don't know how to use it.
Below is the part of code where I inserted the overlay.

```
Button("label") {
                    displayAppBanner.toggle()
                }
                .appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $displayAppBanner) {
                    SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "111111", position: .bottom)
                }
```

The variable is:

```
@Binding var displayAppBanner: Bool
```

Here the link to Xcode documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skoverlay/3566701-dismiss

Comment: Could you share the view, so that we get more context?

Comment: "...wish I could dismiss it with some conditions.."
I think you have the condition already in `displayAppBanner`. Just click on the `label` button again and 
the "banner" will disappear. And if you want to programmatically dismiss it, then toggle `displayAppBanner` 
in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically dismiss the "banner", then make `displayAppBanner = false` in your code.

You could also do this for user interface dismiss:

```
    .appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $displayAppBanner) {
        let config = SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "1440611372", position: .bottom)
        config.userDismissible = true
        return config
    }
```

then, swipe-down the banner to dismiss it.